# TensorFlow, predict predict X,Y location from rssi input

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, training-data, tensor

I'm new in tensorflow and try to create a model that will predict the X and Y coordinates based INPUT which consists of 86 variables that determine the strength of the signal received from the 86 scans located in the building. I have 340 test data. I parsed them and put them in two .csv files.

The first set contains the ordered signal strengths. I saved it as data.csv.
[data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryITO.png)

The second file contains the coordinates on which the meter was at that time. I saved it as labes.csv.
[labels.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni2AB.png)

I have already created a model, but unfortunately its accuracy changes only two training steps. If I want to make tf.summary.merge_all(), this error will appear: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwCJD.png). If I remove this line, the training goes to a successful end, but accuracy does not change except for the first two steps: 
 [training steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDWmh.png)

Error message here:

Nan in summary histogram for: Biases

```
 [[Node: Biases = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Biases/tag, Bias/read)]]
```

Caused by op 'Biases', defined at:

File "E:\Programy\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_launcher.py", line 78, in

```
vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
```

File "E:\Programy\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_debugger.py", line 2483, in debug

```
exec_file(file, globals_obj)
```

File "E:\Programy\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 111, in exec_file

```
exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
```

File "E:\Programy\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 87, in exec_code

```
exec(code_obj, global_variables)
```

File "C:\Users\Tesi\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\LocationDetectionTensorflow\LocationDetectionTensorflow\LocationDetectionTensorflow.py", line 41, in

```
tf.summary.histogram("Biases", b)
```

File "C:\Users\Tesi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\summary.py", line 193, in histogram

```
tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)
```

File "C:\Users\Tesi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py", line 215, in _histogram_summary

```
"HistogramSummary", tag=tag, values=values, name=name)
```

File "C:\Users\Tesi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper

```
op_def=op_def)
```

File "C:\Users\Tesi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3160, in create_op

```
op_def=op_def)
```

File "C:\Users\Tesi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1625, in **init**

```
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
```

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary histogram for: Biases

```
 [[Node: Biases = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Biases/tag, Bias/read)]]
```

Data.csv here:

100,94,99,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,90,79,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,85,100,78,77,79,78,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,89

100,100,100,100,100,87,100,87,100,97,100,90,90,100,100,100,100,100,100,92,100,100,100,100,95,100,100,100,100,88,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,64,64,74,74,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,73,100,100,100,100,100,100,88,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100...

Labels.csv here:

450,2300

1750,900
...

Code here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt("dataExcel.csv", delimiter=';')
labels = np.genfromtxt("labelsExcel.csv", delimiter=';')

inputs = 86
outputs = 2

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, inputs], name='input_X')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, outputs], name='output_Y')
tf.summary.histogram("input_X",x)
tf.summary.histogram("output_Y",y)

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([86, 2]), name="Weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]), name="Bias")
tf.summary.histogram("Weights", W)
tf.summary.histogram("Biases", b)

with tf.name_scope("softmax") as scope:
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

with tf.name_scope("cross_entropy_also_cost_function") as scope:
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(softmax))
    tf.summary.scalar("cross_entropy", cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope("train") as scope:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(softmax,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(prediction,tf.float32))
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    avg_cost = 0.
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/Location")
    writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
    for i in range(1001):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: train_batch_x, y: train_batch_y})
        avg_cost += sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: train_batch_x, y: train_batch_y})
        tf.summary.scalar("avrage cost", avg_cost)
        merged_summary_string = sess.run(merged_summary, feed_dict={x: train_batch_x, y: train_batch_y})
        writer.add_summary(merged_summary_string, i)
        train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: train_batch_x, y: train_batch_y})
        print("STEP:", i,"=>", train_accuracy,"% accuracy.")
        writer.close()
```

So my question is: how can I fix my model to predict X and Y coordinates?

Thank you for every advice or at least effort! Have a nice day!

Update: 
So i should replace my sotfmax function:

```
with tf.name_scope("softmax") as scope:
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
```

with this?:

```
with tf.name_scope("softmax") as scope:
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()'
```

But what is the input into this function?

Comment: Please include the CSVs and console output as text, not images, in your question.

Comment: NaNs can mean many things in tensorflow. Usually invalid data or too large learning rates. Hard to tell without more debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added how data.csv and labels.csv look. Also added error code! 

Thank you for every advice.

Comment: Implementing the cross-entropy by taking the log of the output of the softmax is not numerically stable and can lead to NaNs. Did you try using tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits insteadd?

Comment: I edited my code. I tried to use function you suggested, but i dont know, what the input should be?